# How does PdfEncryptionSettings API work in Itext?

Tags: c#, itext

It may be I'm not familiar with the iText library, but I've got the code below for protecting the document and used "PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING" for Encryption setting:

```
 using (Stream output = new FileStream(_outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
 {
      PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(_pdfReader, output, true, docKey, docKey, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING);
      output.Close();
 }
```

The output file it generated does have the password protection, but after I open it, the pdf could still be edited, I could change bookmarks, add comments, etc and save the changes.

Is there anything I may have missed, or how should we understand the permission settings here? My iText version is 5.5.10.0

Comment: Are you able to instantiate a PdfWriter in this context? There is a method PdfWriter.SetEncryption with similar parameters. Works fine for me (v4.1.6) What editing tool do you use?

Comment: Thanks for inspiration, actually the code above would work too, the issue was owner password is the same with user passowrd. @COeDev

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the code above is the same user password and owner password are used. Making them different and opening document with user password resolved the issue